# How to make lists equal a quadrilateral in Python?

Tags: python, list, shapes

I am having difficulty figuring out to make user-entered lists of numbers equal a quadrilateral, specifically a rhombus and square, in Python. I do not know if my code needs a function or loops or if/else statements to know if it is a rhombus or square.

So far, I have this, but I can't figure out how to go through each side to find out if they are equal to each other or if angle 1 equals angle 2, etc. Which afterwards, I would determine if it the numbers that the user entered made a list that equaled a rhombus or square. Excuse the confusing sentences, I tried to make my problem as clear as possible. Thank you for taking your time to help, if you do!

Edit: I tried a function, but found that it was too complicated by itself. I want to figure out how to search through each list's elements and make sure that they equal/match each other. Thank you!

A rhombus has

1. All four sides the same length
2. Angle 1 equals Angle 3
3. Angle 2 equals Angle 4

A square has

1. All four sides the same length.
2. All angles equal to each other

```
while True:

# Input, Validation, Repetition

    print("=== Please enter Sides ===\n")
    sList = [] # list for sides
    for i in range(0,4,1):
        sides = float(input("Please enter side %i : " %(i + 1 ) ) )
        if sides < 0:
            sides = float(input("Value must be positive! Please enter side %i : " %(i + 1 )))
        sList.append(sides)
    print()

    print("=== Please enter angles ===\n")
    aList = [] # list for angles
    for i in range(0,4,1):
        angles = float(input("Please enter angle %i : " %(i + 1 ) ) )
        if angles < 0:
            angles = float(input("Value must be positive! Please enter angle %i : " %(i + 1 )))
        aList.append(angles)
    print("=======================\n")

# Rhombus
    if sList == sList and aList[1] == aList[3] and aList[2] == aList[4]:
        print("This is a rhombus\n")
#Square
    if sList == aList:
        print("This is a square!\n")

    keep = input("Would you like to repeat? (1-Yes, 2-No): ")
    if keep != '1':
        break
```

Comment: You're going to get a `'float' object is not subscriptable` error. To fix that, try `if sList[1]` etc, instead of `if sides[1]` etc. likewise go for `if aList[1]` etc. instead of `if angles[1]` etc.

Comment: @Vin that didn't work for me, is there a way to go through each element and make sure they're equal to each other in the list?

Comment: Yep there're a few ways to do that. one elegant way might be to turn your `list` of sides into a `set`, A `set` in Python can only store unique values. So if you take a list with four identical values and turn it into a set, the set will contain only one value. So if the length of that set is `1`, you know the list that you converted to a set contained only identical members.

Comment: And FWIW, I would probably have gone with a function, like you were originally intending - serve that function with `sList` and `aList`, and put all your conditional code inside the function. Except - when you define the function, put it outside the `while True` block - you don't need your function recreated everytime you loop - create the function once, then call it inside the loop.

Comment: "I am having difficulty figuring out to make user-entered lists of numbers equal a quadrilateral" I have absolutely no idea what this is supposed to mean. A quadrilateral is a kind of shape. Numbers are numbers. They have nothing to do with shapes. Also, you say that this is about "making" one thing "equal" another, which sounds like trying to do some kind of conversion. But then you show code that seems to be trying to **check whether** some things are equal or not. Please read [ask] and try to think more carefully about the problem, and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach that should work.

First, define a function that evaluates your conditions to check whether something is a rhombus.

```
def is_rhombus(sList, aList):
    if len(set(sList)) == 1 and aList[0] == aList[2] and aList[1] == aList[3]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

`is_rhombus` checks whether the set obtained by converting `sList` into a set has a length of 1 - if yes, that means all members of `sList` were equal to each other. It also checks whether opposite angles in `aList` are equal to each other. if both conditions are satisfied, it returns `True`, else returns `False`.

Next, because we know all rhombuses are squares, but not necessarily the other way round, we create another function called `is_square`:

```
def is_square(sList, aList):
    if is_rhombus(sList, aList) and len(set(aList)) == 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

`is_square` also takes `sList` and `aList`, and it calls the previously defined function `is_rhombus`. If the shape IS a rhombus, `is_square` checks whether in addition to being a `rhombus`, all the angles are equal - using the same approach employed by `is_rhombus` above.

Finally, with both these functions defined, we enter your `while True` loop, and after we get the sides and angles from the user, we go into a little `if-elif-else` block where we first check whether the shape is a square - because that's the narrowest option available to us. If the shape is a square, we print a message to the screen accordingly. If it's not a square, it could still be a rhombus, so we check for that. If it is a rhombus, we print that message to screen. If it's not even a rhombus, we say it's not a rhombus (no point also saying it's not a square - if it's not a rhombus, it can't possibly be a square).

```
while True:

# Input, Validation, Repetition

    print("=== Please enter Sides ===\n")
    sList = [] # list for sides
    for i in range(0,4,1):
        sides = float(input("Please enter side %i : " %(i + 1 ) ) )
        if sides < 0:
            sides = float(input("Value must be positive! Please enter side %i : " %(i + 1 )))
        sList.append(sides)
    print()

    print("=== Please enter angles ===\n")
    aList = [] # list for angles
    for i in range(0,4,1):
        angles = float(input("Please enter angle %i : " %(i + 1 ) ) )
        if angles < 0:
            angles = float(input("Value must be positive! Please enter angle %i : " %(i + 1 )))
        aList.append(angles)
    print("=======================\n")

# Rhombus
    if is_square(sList, aList):
        print ('This is a square!')
    elif is_rhombus(sList, aList):
        print ('This is a rhombus!')
    else:
        print ('This is not a rhombus.')
        
    keep = input("Would you like to repeat? (1-Yes, 2-No): ")
    if keep != '1':
        break
```

Trialling this on a square:

```
=== Please enter Sides ===


Please enter side 1 : 40

Please enter side 2 : 40

Please enter side 3 : 40

Please enter side 4 : 40

=== Please enter angles ===


Please enter angle 1 : 90

Please enter angle 2 : 90

Please enter angle 3 : 90

Please enter angle 4 : 90
=======================

This is a square!

Would you like to repeat? (1-Yes, 2-No): n
```

Trialling this on a rhombus:

```
=== Please enter Sides ===


Please enter side 1 : 40

Please enter side 2 : 40

Please enter side 3 : 40

Please enter side 4 : 40

=== Please enter angles ===


Please enter angle 1 : 60

Please enter angle 2 : 120

Please enter angle 3 : 60

Please enter angle 4 : 120
=======================

This is a rhombus!

Would you like to repeat? (1-Yes, 2-No): n
```

Lastly, trialling it on a non-rhombus:

```
=== Please enter Sides ===


Please enter side 1 : 5

Please enter side 2 : 6

Please enter side 3 : 4

Please enter side 4 : 3

=== Please enter angles ===


Please enter angle 1 : 10

Please enter angle 2 : 20

Please enter angle 3 : 40

Please enter angle 4 : 30
=======================

This is not a rhombus.

Would you like to repeat? (1-Yes, 2-No): n
```

Of course it bears remembering that any shape with four equal sides is a rhombus. That opposite angles will be equal to each other is an attribute of rhombuses, not a criterion for something to be a rhombus. Recognising this, you could redefine your `is_rhombus` function differently to ignore `aList` altogether, and rely only on `sList` to tell us whether the shape is a rhombus.

```
def is_rhombus(sList):
    if sum(sList)/4 == sList[0]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Then, we change the way we call these functions - if the shape isn't a rhombus, why make the user enter a bunch of angles? You could rearrange your `while True` block like this:

```
while True:

# Input, Validation, Repetition

    print("=== Please enter Sides ===\n")
    sList = [] # list for sides
    for i in range(0,4,1):
        sides = float(input("Please enter side %i : " %(i + 1 ) ) )
        if sides < 0:
            sides = float(input("Value must be positive! Please enter side %i : " %(i + 1 )))
        sList.append(sides)
    print()
    
    if is_rhombus(sList):
        print("=== Please enter angles ===\n")
        aList = [] # list for angles
        for i in range(0,4,1):
            angles = float(input("Please enter angle %i : " %(i + 1 ) ) )
            if angles < 0:
                angles = float(input("Value must be positive! Please enter angle %i : " %(i + 1 )))
            aList.append(angles)
        print("=======================\n")
        
        if is_square(sList, aList):
            print ('This is a square!')
        else:
            print ('This is a rhombus!')
    else:
        print ('This is not a rhombus.')


    keep = input("Would you like to repeat? (1-Yes, 2-No): ")
    if keep != '1':
        break
```

This behaviour is identical to before - except if four unequal sides are provided, we don't bother asking for a bunch of angles.

Comment: thank you so much, that worked. I was looking for a function like `set`, and yes you were right about the functions. I was doubting myself because I could not find anything like set, thank you again, Vin!

Answer (score 0):

**First we need some tweaking in the edge control.**

Because "if sides[i] == sides[i]:" statement returns always True.
Instead, let's write a function that checks that all edges are the same.

```
def is_same_edges(edges) -> bool:
    sum_edges = sum(edges)
    return (sum_edges / len(edges)) == edges[0]
```

This function calculates the sum of all the elements in the list it takes as a parameter. Then it divides the length of the list it takes as a parameter and checks it with any of the lists element. If it is the same, all the elements are the same.

**Now that we've done the edge checks, we can move on to the angle check.**

```
def is_opposite_angles_same(angles) -> bool:
    return angles[0] == angles[2] and angles[1] == angles[3]
```

This function returns whether the opposite angles are equal.

**Okay, we have the functions we need. Now let's edit your function.**

```
def rhombus(sList, aList):
    if is_same_edges(sList) and is_opposite_angles_same(aList):
            rhombus = sList
            print(rhombus)
```